# Install local portainer with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, portainer

I'm reading the docker-ce dock for installation. It's simple two lines :

```
docker volume create portainer_data &&
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9443:9443 --name portainer --restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data  portainer/portainer-ce:latest
```

Is there a way to do all this stuff with docker-compose file ? So the portainer container will be groupped with all the others when executing `docker-comppose down` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This french tutorial](https://computerz.solutions/docker-compose-portainer/) got something working :

```
  portainer:
    container_name: portainer
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest #latest might not be the best option
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:fr
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:fr
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:fr #not sure about those 3 volumes
      - dataportainer:/data
volumes:
  dataportainer:
```